# How do I map the middle button of a Mighty Mouse to open a new tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, mighty-mouse

Is it possible to map the middle click of my Apple Mighty Mouse (connected to a MacBook Pro) to open a new tab in Google Chrome (on OSX Snow Leopard)?

This works in Firefox, and (I think) on Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you map it to "Button 3" in *System Preferences > Mouse*, does that work?

[image]

Comment: It does. Was "off" before, did not know it was. Thanks!